# Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging error in Event log as Event ID 6352

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 for error loggin in WCF application. I have logging into SQL Database and if Database is down then logging into EventLog.

Problem is if Database is down or connection string is incorrect it logging in Appication Event Log with Event ID 6352 with all details.

Problem is if I am sending log to SQL server and sending Event ID as 5000, I want Enterprise Library to log in Event Log with Event ID 5000.

But Enterprise Library logging as Event ID 6352 and inside error detail I have Event ID 5000.

How can I Log in Event Viewer with Event ID 5000 when SQL Server is down.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Event ID for internal errors cannot be modified without changing the code for the LogWriter class, for which the source code is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=46&SrcFamilyId=BCB166F7-DD16-448B-A152-9845760D9B4C&SrcDisplayLang=en&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fA%2f5%2fB%2fA5BF3B05-CB8A-40FE-B3E0-93FA84136D2B%2fEnterprise+Library+5.0+-+Source+Code.msi) and the license permits you to do so.

You may also want to [suggest](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general) this as a feature request for future versions of EntLib.